# How can I properly display an image from Laravel's public folder using React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, public-folders

I've tried using the asset() function below, but it returns the current path and localhost, when I only want the localhost where the image is located

```
const assetUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_HOST;

function asset(path) {
    const assetUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_HOST;
    return `${assetUrl}/public/images/${path}`;
}

const imageUrl = asset(currentUser.profil_picture);
```

When I use this code, the resulting imageUrl is incorrect, as it includes the React current path and localhost. Here's an example of the incorrect URL:

```
imageUrl = "http://localhost:5173/news_feed/127.0.0.1:8000/public/images/7c2bbd80-764e-4c6b-9be9-60cabc73b599.png"
```

How can I modify the asset() function to return only the correct localhost URL for the image location?

Comment: Just use currentUser.profil_picture just make sure link start with /

Comment: @PuneetSharma i didn"t undestrand i want to get the picture from laravel public folder not react folder

Comment: Provide more info where you run app is it public folder. Did you runing a standalone react app that direct app toward laravel backend on different server/path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need get `VITE_HOST` .
In **Laravel** you should store your images in `storage/app/public` folder instead of `public` folder. then you should create a link from `public` folder to `storage/app/public` folder.

you can do this by `php artisan storage:link` command.

so let's assume your image is in this path: `storage/app/public/images/avatars/profile.jpg`

and now you can get files in the `public/storage/` folder like this:

```js
const asset = (path) => {
    return `/storage/images/${path}`;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<img src={asset('avatars/profile.jpg')} />
```